# jQuery : getting more parameters than expected

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to select some inputs in my html page,

However I don't know why I'm getting more parameters than what I expect to have :

[image]

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="preferred_language_radio" class="required">
    <label for="locale_fr" class="radio-inline">
        <input id="locale_fr" class="required" type="radio" value="fr_CA" name="member.locale"/>
        Fr
    </label>
    <label for="locale_en" class="radio-inline">
        <input id="locale_en" class="required" type="radio" value="en_CA" name="member.locale"/>
        En
    </label>
</div>
```

Any Idea why I'm getting these parameters ?

thanks

Comment: Yes it's normal, it's all the methods you can use. It's not really important no matter

Comment: I used jQuery in other html pages in the past ... and I get only the inputs (the first two parameters in our case) !!

Comment: Can you show the difference between the 2 pages and put the jQuery code to compare with plz

Comment: Those are internal properties of the jQuery object. You don't need to concern yourself with them.

Comment: You're right Jean-maxime, these paramters exist !